# WPF Manipulation - the more fingers, the slower it goes

Tags: wpf

I'm struggling to get good responsiveness with touch manipulation in WPF. After extensive searching it does seem as though there are some performance issues with WPF and the problems I have are not evident in winrt.

But I have narrowed it down to something interesting. I just have an image on a window, and am manipulating the RenderTransform of the image on the ManipulationDelta event. Only translation, not scale, rotation, etc.

If I use 1 finger, I can move as fast and long as I like and everything keeps up fine (cpu usage is about 6%). But with 2 fingers on the screen, I get lagging and delays, and cpu goes up to 9%,

I tried commenting out everything in the manipulation event, so I am actually doing nothing - my app uses 0% idle and still uses 5% if I move a touch on the screen! This does not seem to be a good starting point for smooth and responsive touch.

And I need to work with at least 2 touches to get pinch zoom working, and it seems the more fingers are on the screen, the worse it gets.

What approach do I need to get smooth multiple finger touch manipulation in WPF? Exactly the same in winrt works fine.

Comment: I think you are forgetting that registering touch is a **Windows process**. The operating system is responsible for listening out for touch events. Unfortunately, I don't think there is much you can do to improve performance.

Comment: it also depends upon your hardware, meaning your touch screen how many touch points it can simultaneously recognize.

Comment: It is not an issue of touch point number capability. The screen can do 10 and I've tested up to 5.

Comment: I have the same problem. did you found solution?

Comment: Are you saying that the image scaling is slower than the image panning? That issue seems unrelated to the touch handling. Is it slow when you scale with the mouse wheel?